# Find all pairs with the given sum, in an unsorted array of numbers

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, sum, combinations

For example, the function will have two inputs:

- An array of any length e.g. `[1, 8, 5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 4]`.
- A target sum e.g. `10`.

The output will be an array of all pairs of numbers that sum to the target e.g. `[(1,9),(8,2),(5,5),(7,3),(6,4)]`.

I am completely stuck with how to create this code. if anyone can provide some insight, below is what i have so far but it doesn't work:

```
sums :: (Num a, Num b) => [a] -> b -> [(a,a)]
sums ([x] i) = (x i)
sums (x:xs) i
    | x == [] = []
    | x + sums(xs) == i = [(x,xs)]
    | otherwise = []
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We don't answer questions here that don't show any own effort at solving the problem. As you're “stuck” you obviously must have tried some own ideas already, so do show them.

Comment: And BTW, `[1,8,5]` in Haskell is not an array but a _list_.

Comment: Unfortunately, your code kind of looks like you threw a bunch of syntax and functions at the wall in the hope that something might stick. It's nothing like valid Haskell, and I can't make head or tail of what it's supposed to mean. Can you please start by explaining, in clear and precise language, how you hope to solve the problem? This may seem like a tedious step, but it's really a good way to get your thoughts in order.

Comment: I'll start with one little tip: your numerical types should surely be the same. Your type signature should probably look like `sums :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]`. A more efficient version of the function would need a more constrained type: `sums :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]` or even `sums :: Integral a => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]`, but you should try the simpler `Eq` version first.

Comment: Is a list element allowed to be used twice? That is, if 5 only appeared once in the input, could you still produce `(5,5)`?

Comment: Can list elements be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're given an unsorted list, sometimes the best first step is to sort it. So let's start out:

```
import Data.List (sort)
sums :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]
sums xs s = ...
  where
    sorted = sort xs
```

Cool. What's next? Let's work through the sorted list from both sides at once. Lists are bad for that, so let's use sequences here.

```
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Sequence (Seq (..), fromList)

sums :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]
sums xs s = go sorted
  where
    sorted = fromList (sort xs)
    go Empty = []
    go (_ :<| Empty) = []
    go (a :<| asb@(as :|> b)) = case compare (a + b) s of
      EQ -> (a,b) : go as
      LT -> go asb
      GT -> go (a :<| as)
```

This will give results in a different order than your example, but it works in O(n log n) time instead of O(n^2) time—much faster for long lists.

There's still an unfortunate inefficiency here: we may take an element off a sequence and put it back on multiple times. It's not a big deal, but it's really easy to fix.

```
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Sequence (Seq (..), fromList)

sums :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]
sums xs s = start sorted
  where
    sorted = fromList (sort xs)
    start Empty = []
    start (_ :<| Empty) = []
    start (a :<| (as :> b)) = go a as b

    go a as b = case compare (a + b) s of
      EQ -> (a,b) : start as
      LT
        | a' :<| as' <- as
        -> go a' as' b
        | otherwise -> []
      GT
        | as' :|> b' <- as
        -> go a as' b'
        | otherwise -> []
```

As was pointed out in a now-deleted comment, `Data.Sequence` is really overkill here. A wide variety of deque-like, multiset-like, and double-ended priority queue structures will work, many of them simpler and/or faster than `Data.Sequence`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's certainly an option, but you'd have to keep careful track of the abstract length. There's also a bit of a space leak that way; you don't release any elements until the whole result is consumed. Certainly `Seq` is overkill. You only need `fromList`, `popL`, and `popR`, and those only need to be fast for ephemeral use. But I didn't want to come up with a special-purpose data structure for this question.

Comment: lists are great for `head` and `tail`; lists are also great for being built in reverse. consider the input `targetSum 10 $ [1,2,9,8,6]++[100..10000]`.

Comment: maybe I'd answer, but I can't, since it's closed now for "lack of details". (I see all the details I need.) ----- re the case in my cmt above, I wonder whether  quicksort would be better than mergesort there....

Comment: @WillNess, I don't really understand what you're getting at. Your specific example would work great with GHC's adaptive mergesort.

Comment: it was two things. first, that we don't need sequences. after sorting my example data we don't even need reversing the whole list. it's enough to access its `take 6` prefix. we'd go along the list while building the reversed prefix, and at the 6th element we'd discover it's enough, for the target sum of 10. the 2nd thing was, not with my specific example which is mostly sorted (yes, this would get discovered in O(n)), but with a similar one, with say 10 elements under 10 at the start and  then 10000 elements all bigger than 10. we'd first partition at 10, etc.

Comment: and I wasn't sure whether that would have any advantage over what mergesort would do, under the `takeWhile (< 10)`.

Comment: @WillNess, there are lots of possible optimizations for different situations. Something like a `Data.Map`-based multiset could repeatedly trim off the irrelevant parts of the tree. You could do that with certain finger tree structures too. Worst case, they're all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt has quite some issues, syntactically and semantically.
Here is one possible solution. It isn't recursive, but I hope it will help you understand the problem (see suggestion at the end about recursion):

```
sums :: (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [(a,a)]
sums l s = filter (\(x,y) -> x+y == s) [ (x,y) | x <- l, y <- l ]
```

- `[ (x,y) | x <- l, y <- l ]` defines a list with all possible pairs
- `\(x,y) -> x+y == s` is a function that given a pair tells whether it satisfies your condition
- `filter` uses that function to filter the list of all possible pairs

Please take your time to learn about a number of topics:

- How to write a function signature
- Lists and most common functions for them (e.g. `filter`)
- Comprehension syntax (`[ (x,y) | x <- l, y <- l ]`)
- Lambda expressions (`\(x,y) -> x+y == s`)
- Lazy evaluation. Your attempt tries to do everything in one function: traversing the list, making pairs, checking if they satisfy the condition.
  The solution above first defines all possible combinations and then filters, selecting only those that sum to `s`. Conceptually simpler, also efficient thought intuitively it might seem slow if you come from imperative programming.

As pointed out in the comments, the most compact way to express this would use comprehension's ability to apply conditions "on-the-fly" to the generated combinations:

```
sums l s = [ (x,y) | x <- l, y <- l, x+y == s ]
```

However it would be more instructive for you to try and solve the problem with recursion.

Suggestion: keep the structure `filter (\(x,y) -> x+y == s) (all_pairs l)`, but try to come up yourself with a recursive function `all_pairs` that generates all possible pairs from a list, instead of using the comprehension syntax as I did.
The function you'll need to write is much simpler than the one you tried before. Just make all pairs from a list, no conditions, no checks.

Comment: You can filter in the list comprehension as well, so `[(x, y) | x <- l, y <- l, x+y == s]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem absolutely. I was not aiming at the best/shortest solution, but at one that would help OP see the original problem as a composition of sub-problems.

Comment: @luqui it seems from the answer's last paragraph that the answerer intended that for the simplicity of the hand-rolled recursive re-write. no distractions for the asker to contend with.